# ??? in page titl - Craft CMS

Tags: seo, title, craftcms

I'm currently using Craft CMS and setting up the SEO info. I've added SEO titles per page which is displayed in the page title. However when I refresh the page four question marks appear in front of the title.

Where are these coming from and how can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: CraftCMS does not have a SEO Preview field, so you probably should provide some information about that. How you created that field and where it is would be helpful.

Comment: …and what is the title attribute of the page shown?